# Saving numpy array to txt file as a single column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to write a numpy array into txt file:

```
a = numpy.array([1,2,3])
numpy.savetxt('a.txt',a,fmt='%.3f')
```

when I open the txt file it looks like:

```
1.0002.0003.000
```

but when I paste it in word it looks like:

```
1.000

2.000

3.000
```

The problem is that another program reads the txt file as input line by line:

```
data = fid.readlines()
```

As a result it doesn't work correctly.How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on the details, but I do know that windows, mac os, and linux use different characters for their newlines. `\n` (carriage return) for unix/linux, `\r` (linefeed) for mac os, and `\n\r` in windows. Open up the file in python and do `print(repr(fid.read()))` and see if what type of newlines it contains.

Comment: Also see this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599936/handling-r-n-vs-n-newlines-in-python-on-mac-vs-windows)

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.savetxt` has a keyword argument `newline` which defaults to `\n` (the unix/linux line break).

You can either set it manually or use `os.linesep` to choose the newline character of your current operating system. So

```
import os
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3])
np.savetxt('a.txt', a, fmt='%.3f', newline=os.linesep)
```

should be in one column with a windows editor and a program which runs under windows should be able to read it.

Comment: Nice. Also, some better text editors (Geany, Notepad++, etc.) can handle this issue automatically in Windows.