# Write first row from .txt-file as a column in new .txt-file

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get the first row of a `file.txt` (*tab* separated strings) and create a new file with one column which is made of the elements of the row I want to extract. I managed to get the first row of the file with

```
f = open("file.txt", "r")
row1 = f.readline()
```

I tried the `("new_file.txt", w)` after transposing with `x.T` but it didn't work. After I get the file I should also split in in 10 smaller files.

This is an example of the input file:

```
rs123  rs15  rs1567  rs43  rs567  rs3564
    1     2       3     4      5       6
    7     8       9    10     11      12
```

and this is what I need:

```
rs123
rs15
rs1567
rs43
rs567
rs3564
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755555/saving-numpy-array-to-txt-file-as-a-single-column

Comment: Please tag your question appropriately, with the language being used, as well as any relevant framework or library.

Comment: is it properly formatted now? Does your file look exactly like this?

Comment: @user2390900, Just so that you know, atomh33ls's solution is ~10 times slower than mine on my simple test file and gets linearly worse with file size. One reason is that it has to trasverse the list 2 times, one for reading, a second for writing. It also uses a lot more memory because it loads the whole file without need which will lead to MemoryError if filesize > RAM.

Comment: I didn't realize that you could choose only one answer... new to this website... sorry and thanks again for your help

Comment: @elyase - can you show details of your speed/resource comparison?

Comment: @atomh33ls, in iPython notebook just add the `%%timeit` magic at the top of the cell. I get `100 loops, best of 3: 1.82 ms per loop` in your version and `1000 loops, best of 3: 193 µs per loop` in mine with a test file similar to the one the OP shows with less that 100 lines. The resource part comes from the documentation of genfromtxt.

Comment: @atomh33ls, are you getting something different?

Comment: @elyase - Your method performs a lot better for me as well:  Yours: `100 loops best of 3 = 1.34 ms per loop`; Mine: `100 loops best of 3 = 0.574 ms per loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('inFile.txt', 'r') as inFile, open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outFile:
    outFile.writelines(line + '\n' for line in inFile.readline().split('\t'))
```

To split the file in smaller parts I would use unix split, for example:

```
split -l $lines_per_file outfile.txt
```

To find `$lines_per_file` divide the total number of lines `wc -l output.txt` by 10.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [genfromtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) and [savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) routines:

If you want to save strings (as per the amended question):

```
import numpy as np
with open('new_file.txt','w') as f:
   for el in np.genfromtxt('file.txt',dtype=None)[0]:
     f.write(str(el)+'\n')
```

If the data is numerical:

```
import numpy as np
x=np.genfromtxt('file.txt')[0] 
np.savetxt('new_file.txt',x)
```

You could even combine these into one line:

```
np.savetxt('myfile2.dat',np.genfromtxt('myfile.dat')[0])
```

Comment: Thank you, this would work if I had numbers but the output is a col of nan because I have strings. I tried to set dtype="S10" or dtype="object" but it doesn't work.

Comment: This won't work as numpy arrays must have homogenous data, only strings or only floats.

Comment: Updated to reflect the changed question.