# Python : Comma at the end of print statement

Tags: python

I've just started learning python from the source `learnjavathehardway`.

There was a "fun" code that goes as follows

```
while True:
    for i in ["/","-","|","\\","|"]:
        print "%s\r" % i,
```

Now what it does is that at the same place in my console, it prints the different character one by one. (Try it yourself if you did not get what I said)

Basically,it prints `/ - | \ |` in quick succession, **at the same place**.

If I remove comma from the end of print statement, it prints each character in a new line.

Now I want to know, why is it printing out at the same place? And not one after the other?  Thanks

Comment: If the site is called *Learn **Java** the Hard Way,* don't be surprised if they can't teach you Python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because of the `\r`, which is the [`carriage return <CR>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) character in ascii. It basically resets the cursor to the start of the line.

The comma at the end of that line is because in python 2.7, the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) *statement* adds a newline. Using the comma, the newline is not added.

In python 3.x, `print` is no longer a statement but a function. You can provide the `end` keyword-argument to [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) to determine the ending character, which defaults to a newline, `\n`.

Comment: Ohh, did not see that. Thanks alot. :)

Comment: Wow, didn't know that `\r` and `,` in print worked that way - to print things in the same line (in Python2). Is the `\r`+`,` behaviour different on Mac since the newlines are different codes? Since it's [not reading from a file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4599936/1431750) I wouldn't think it's automatically handled for a `print` statement/function.

Comment: I believe that the functionality is cross-platform. The `carriage return` is the same in all of the three major platforms, it's just the line separator that differs (from `\r\n` to `\n`), e.g windows prepends the carriage return to the line feed.