# Python only a '\n' char

Tags: python, char, newline

When I do this

```
print >>file, "\n"
```

This actually writes a "\r\n" on my Windows machine.  How do I write only the "\n" char and not the "\r"?

Comment: You can see some discussion on this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599936/handling-r-n-vs-n-newlines-in-python-on-mac-vs-windows)

Comment: That's not going to write `'\r\n'`. It might write `'\n\r\n'` or `'\r\n\r\n'`, depending on whether you opened the file in text or binary mode, but not `'\r\n'`. (Also, you probably want binary mode.)

Comment: nbryans is correct. You want either the universal newlines or newline='\n' when you open the file