# python copying text from one file to another

Tags: python, powershell, copying

I'm following Zed A. Shaw's lpthw  example 17 if you want to look at it https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex17.html and it works just with only one line but not multiple (using terminal, windows powershell)
the original file says
 "This is a test you are being tested why does it not work on multiple lines the 2nd line says see but capitalized
SEE"
 the 2nd file that copied the text and pasted it using write command says this 
"This is a test you are being tested why does it not work on multiple lines the 2nd line says see but capitalized
਍ऀ匀䔀䔀" I don't understand it i even copied his code and there isn't a single change in his or mine yet neither

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

# we could do these two on one line, how?
in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
raw_input()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

print "Alright, all done."

out_file.close()
in_file.close()`
```

I don't want to change the code much just because I know this works for a single line and beleive without much change it can work with an entire essay for example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python concatenate text files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files)

Comment: LPTHW is regarded as a sub-par tutorial, by the way. The official tutorial is much better.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the correct encoding for the file you are reading when you open it 
`open(file, mode='r', buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True, opener=None)`

Answer (score 0):

You may be having this problem due to the difference in which new lines are handled in Windows vs Linux. 
Have a look at : [Handling \r\n vs \n newlines in python on Mac vs Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599936/handling-r-n-vs-n-newlines-in-python-on-mac-vs-windows)