# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' while parsing text

Tags: python

I am processing a text file with 6400 numbers separated by a comma in an 80 x 80 matrix, however I am getting an;

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

What's strange is that this code works on windows but not mac (same python version)

I've tried checking for extra spaces and commas by using try and except to no avail

```
def read_numbers(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        text = f.read()
        text = text.replace("\n", ",")

    numbers = []
    for s in text.split(','):
        try:
            numbers.append(int(s))
        except ValueError, e:
            print "error",e, "with", "(",s,")"
    return numbers
```

Comment: Nevertheless, you clearly have a line which contains an empty space between two commas or alone on a line. Looks like at the very least the final newline would be problematic.

Comment: pass only number inside `int()`

Comment: add your file sample to check it

Comment: Post a sample data from `file`

Comment: Have you checked what line separators are used in your file? Is it really a single `\n` or is there some `\r` somwhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a trailing `,` on the end of a line. When the newline is converted into a `,` this would result in `,,`. Your `split(',')` would then result in a list containing an empty string. This would cause the invalid literal exception.

As an alternative, you could use a regular expression to extract all the integers. This would then automatically cope with possible blank lines or missing values:

```
import re

def read_numbers(filename):        
    with open(filename) as f:
        return list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', f.read())))
```

Comment: @po-chen-liu Why did you have a trailing `,` at the end of a line, `this code works on windows but not mac`?

Answer (score 2):

This `text = text.replace("\n", ",")` is not needed, neither should you do `for s in text.split(','):`:

```
numbers = []
def read_numbers(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        content = f.read()

        # you may also want to remove empty lines
        content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]

    for s in content:

        try:
            numbers.append(int(s))
        except ValueError:
            print("error with {}".format(s))

    return numbers
```

**EDIT:**

I tried to reproduce your problem with the following:

list.txt:

```
12,43,54,65,7676,87,9898,0909,676,46556

2342,6556,7687
5465,76878,98090,9090,5656


33,434,3435,4545 ,5656
```

and then:

```
numbers = []
def read_numbers(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
    for s in content.split(","):

        if ',' in s or '\n' in s:
            continue
        else:
            numbers.append(s)

    return numbers


print(read_numbers("list.txt"))
```

OUTPUT:

```
['12', '43', '54', '65', '7676', '87', '9898', '0909', '676', '6556', '76878', '98090', '9090', '434', '3435', '4545 ', '5656']
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599936/handling-r-n-vs-n-newlines-in-python-on-mac-vs-windows), your source code only supports Window version. So I guess that your `s` variable at this line `numbers.append(int(s))` include newline character on its.

[Document here](https://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/functions.html#open): The key point from that documentation is this

> Newline controls how universal newlines works (it only applies to text
>   mode). It can be None, '', '\n', '\r', and '\r\n'. It works as
>   follows:
>
> - On input, if the newline is None, universal newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in '\n', '\r', or '\r\n', and
>     these are translated into '\n' before being returned to the caller. If
>     it is '', universal newline mode is enabled, but line endings are
>     returned to the caller untranslated. If it has any of the other legal
>     values, input lines are only terminated by the given string, and the
>     line ending is returned to the caller untranslated.
> - On output, if the newline is None, any '\n' characters written are translated to the system default line separator, os.linesep. If
>     newline is '', no translation takes place. If newline is any of the
>     other legal values, any '\n' characters written are translated to the
>     given string.

Solution:

```
# When you open a file in text mode in Python 3, It will convert all newlines to '\n' and be done with it.
def read_numbers(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read()
        text = text.replace("\n", ",")

    numbers = []
    for s in text.split(','):
        try:
            numbers.append(int(s))
        except ValueError, e:
            print "error",e, "with", "(",s,")"
    return numbers
```